# error al insertar mediante el servlet controlador

Tags: java, mysql

Si alguien por favor conoce la solución, mi problema es que estoy manejando un **servlet** controlador y estoy intentando insertar datos a la **base de datos** pero no me inserta dice que **javalangnullpointer** ya hice debug y si me esta trayendo todas las variables que capturo en el formulario.

Lo más raro de todo es que si yo inserto desde un método **main**, es decir, le envío los datos directos al método **create**, me inserta sin problema, de esta manera le envío al método **create** para probar si esta funcionando y así sí funciona.

No entiendo por qué cuando utilizo el envío de los datos del formulario no me inserta en la tabla de la base de datos.

```
package Modelo.EmpleadoDAO;

import Modelo.Conexion;
import Modelo.Interfaces.Obligatorio;
import Modelo.VO.EmpleadoVO;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author MIGUEL ANGEL
 */
public class EmpleadoDAO implements Obligatorio<EmpleadoVO>



{

// Querys para trabajar sobre  la base de datos 
// E.create(new EmpleadoVO(147,"Jesus","Angel","Camargo","Vanegas","1245-07-24","1214-12-04","M",22,"casado",1,"avenida","bogota","b",2,"Programador","donatllo","Antonio Casale",3800.000)); 
 private static final String SQL_Insert="INSERT INTO Empleado (Nit,Primer_nombre,Segundo_nombre,Apellido_paterno,Apellido_materno,Fecha_nacimiento,Fecha_ingreso,Genero,Edad,Estado_civil,Numero_hijos,Direccion,Ciudad,Grupo_sanguineo,Experiencia_anos,Profesion,Email,Jefe_inmediato,Sueldo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
 private static final String SQL_Delete="DELETE FROM Empleado WHERE Nit = ?";
 private static final String SQL_Update="UPDATE Empleado SET  Primer_nombre = ?,Segundo_nombre=?,Apellido_paterno = ?,Apellido_materno = ?,Grupo_sanguineo = ?,Estado_civil = ?,Numero_hijos = ?,Email = ?,Edad = ?,Fecha_ingreso = ?,Jefe_inmediato = ?,Experiencia_anos = ?,Sueldo = ?,Profesion = ?,Genero = ?,Direccion = ?,Ciudad = ? WHERE Nit = ?";
 private static final String SQL_Read="SELECT * FROM Empleado WHERE Nit = ?";
 private static final String SQL_Readall="SELECT * FROM Empleado";
//  private static final String SQL_Insert="INSERT INTO Empleado (Nit) VALUES (?) ";

 private static final Conexion con=Conexion.estado();

@Override
public boolean create(EmpleadoVO c)
{
         PreparedStatement ps;

     try {

         ps=con.getConecta().prepareStatement(SQL_Insert);


         ps.setInt(1,c.getNit());
         ps.setString(2,c.getPrimer_nombre());
         ps.setString(3,c.getSegundo_nombre());
         ps.setString(4,c.getApellido_paterno());
         ps.setString(5,c.getApellido_materno());
         ps.setString(6,c.getFecha_nacimiento());
         ps.setString(7,c.getFecha_ingreso());
         ps.setString(8,c.getGenero());
         ps.setInt(9,c.getEdad());
         ps.setString(10,c.getEstado_civil());
         ps.setInt(11,c.getNumero_hijos());
         ps.setString(12,c.getDireccion());
         ps.setString(13,c.getCiudad()); 
         ps.setString(14,c.getGrupo_sanguineo());
         ps.setInt(15,c.getExperiencia());
         ps.setString(16,c.getProfesion());
         ps.setString(17,c.getEmail());
         ps.setString(18,c.getJefe_inmediato());
         ps.setDouble(19,c.getSalario());

         if(ps.executeUpdate()>0);
         {
             return true;

         }


     } catch (SQLException ex) 
     {
         Logger.getLogger(EmpleadoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }finally
     {
         con.desconectar();
     }

      return false;
}
```

Comment: saludos brother, bienvenido a SOes, te invito a pasear por http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y darte una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que familiarices con el sitio. Te parece si agregas la vista?

Comment: ¿Que tan necesario es tener una tabla con 19 columnas?¿No te convendría hacer varias tablas con menos columnas?

Comment: MatiEzelQ gracias por responder ya hice la prueba tratando de hacer la inserción con menos datos pero tampoco inserta.

Comment: Hola @user15759 por favor agrega el stacktrace que es el mensaje extenso que dice la ubicación exacta del `NullPointerException`. Con esto en mano podremos decirte dónde está el error. Sin ello, cuesta más trabajo y es menos certero.

Comment: Muestra  la  parte de código del servlet, si truena cuando lo usas, posiblemente una instancia no se está creando, que  puede ser al momento de llamar al DAO, pero mejor muestra el stack trace.

Comment: soy nuevo en este foro como puedo compartir el codigo @Voiser